# Explain the O(N) time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Can anybody explain the O(N) time complexity for the following algorithm:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Complexity theory questions like this are typically better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i am sorry guys, this is my first time on stackoverflow,

Answer (score 2):

The number of incrementations of `count` is `N+N/2+N/4+N/8+...<2N`

Answer (score 1):

If you wite the time complexity recursively you will have `T(n) = T(n/2) + n`. Using master theorem you can get the result, as `c = log_2(1) = 0` and `n = \Omega(n^c)` (the third case of master theorem). Hence, `T(n) = \Theta(n)` or `T(n) = O(n)`.